# How to return count in 2 columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this query. It should return Count for both AWARDED (1) and NOT AWARDED(0) works from works table.

```
        Select Count(w.WorkID)as Total, w.IsAwarded, org.OrganizationName
        From Works w
        Inner Join MC_MemberShip.Membership.Organization org
        ON org.OrganizationID= w.Organization_ID
        where Convert(varchar(11), w.OpeningDate) >= Convert(varchar(11), @FromDate) 
        and  Convert(varchar(11), w.OpeningDate) < DATEADD(day, 1, Convert(varchar(11), @ToDate))
        and w.IsActive=1 and 
        ISNULL(w.IsAwarded,0)= 0 and w.Organization_ID= case when @OrgID= -1 then w.Organization_ID else @OrgID end
        group by org.OrganizationName, w.IsAwarded
```

Now this query returns Total count for NOT AWARDED i.e. 0 only but i want to return count for AWARDED too in same query.

```
Organization    TotalAwardedWorks    TotalNotAwardedWorks
Town 1              1                        2
Town 2              44                       33
```

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff done, pleas check question

Comment: @jarlh: already done,

Comment: Is that table data, or the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

Your query should look something like this:

```
select org.OrganizationName,
       Count(*) as Total,
       sum(case when w.IsAwarded = 0 or w.IsAwarded is null then 1 else 0 end) as TotalNotAward,
       sum(case when w.IsAwarded = 1 then 0 else 1 end) as TotalAward
from Works w Inner Join
     MC_MemberShip.Membership.Organization org
     on org.OrganizationID = w.Organization_ID
where w.OpeningDate >= @FromDate and
      w.OpeningDate < dateadd(day, 1, @ToDate) and
      w.IsActive = 1 and 
      (w.Organization_ID = @OrgId or @OrgID= -1)
group by org.OrganizationName;
```

Notes:

- Do not convert dates to strings to perform comparisons.  That is just perverse.
- Generally, the use of `case` in the `where` clause is discouraged.  The logic is more clearly represented using `or`.
- You can get what you want by using `case` to put conditions in the aggregation functions.

Comment: sum(case when w.IsAwarded = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as TotalAwarded,
       sum(case when w.IsAwarded = 0 or w.IsAwarded is null then 0 else 1 end) as TotalNotAwarded